# Two views of a same memory mapped file in windows, how do they interact flush-wise?

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files

I'm specifically interested in the flush behaviour.

Suppose we created a MMF with CreateFileMapping(), and opened two views, V1 and V2 using MapViewOfFile() with zero offset.

Then I write something to A=V1+a and something to B=V2+b such that A and B belong to different physical memory pages.

Then if I flush the whole first view using FlushViewOfFile(V1, 0), will the dirty pages of the second view also be affected?

My goal is to have 2 views of the same file, where the first view is used for very small writes and very frequent flushes, while the second view is used for massive writes and is flushed only once in a while.

It is important that flushing small writes wouldn't cause flushing of massive writes.

Is this a default behaviour? If not, how to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[CreateFileMappingA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga), see also [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), [DuplicateHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle) and [OpenFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilemappinga) functions.

> "Creating a file mapping object does not actually map the view into a
> process address space. The [MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) and [MapViewOfFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffileex)
> functions map a view of a file into a process address space.
> With one important exception, **file views derived from any file mapping object** that is backed by the same file **are coherent
> or identical at a specific time**. **Coherency is guaranteed for views
> within a process and for views that are mapped by different
> processes.**
> The exception is related to remote files. Although CreateFileMapping works with remote files, it does not keep them
> coherent. For example, if two computers both map a file as writable,
> and both change the same page, each computer only sees its own writes
> to the page. When the data gets updated on the disk, it is not
> merged."

According to the [FlushViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-flushviewoffile),

> "Flushing a range of a mapped view **initiates** writing of dirty
> pages within that range to the disk. Dirty pages are those whose
> contents have changed since the file view was mapped. The
> **FlushViewOfFile** function does not flush the file metadata, and it **does not wait to return until the changes are flushed from the underlying hardware disk cache and physically written to disk**. To
> flush all the dirty pages plus the metadata for the file and ensure
> that they are physically written to disk, call FlushViewOfFile and
> then call the [FlushFileBuffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers) function."

So, when you close views in [UnmapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Memory/closing-a-file-mapping-object)

> "When a process has finished with the file mapping object, it should
> destroy all file views in its address space by using the
> UnmapViewOfFile function for each file view.
>
> **Unmapping a mapped view of a file invalidates the range occupied by the view in the address space of the process and makes the range
> available for other allocations**. It removes the working set entry
> for each unmapped virtual page that was part of the working set of the
> process and reduces the working set size of the process. **It also
> decrements the share count of the corresponding physical page.**
>
> **Modified pages in the unmapped view are not written to disk until their share count reaches zero**, or in other words, **until they are
> unmapped or trimmed from the working sets of all processes that share
> the pages**. Even then, the modified pages are written "lazily" to
> disk; that is, modifications may be cached in memory and written to
> disk at a later time. To minimize the risk of data loss in the event
> of a power failure or a system crash, **applications should explicitly
> flush modified pages using the FlushViewOfFile function**."

Comment: Thanks, Artur, but this doesn't answer the actual question. I know that the views are coherent, but this is not related to flushing behaviour.